# PdfReader from MemoryStream()

Tags: c#, itext, memorystream, pdf-reader

Can anyone give me an example of how to get a `PdfReader` from a `MemoryStream`?  I can see that the `PdfReader` class has a couple of methods which look like likely candidates (`GetStreamBytes` & `GetStreamBytesRaw`), however these seem to want `iText`-specific streams, mine is just a regular `Byte[]` or `MemoryStream`.

This is using C# and .NET 4.

```
iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader rdr = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader.GetStreamBytesRaw
```

Comment: what u mean pdfreader from memorystream? are you trying to generate a pdf from already available bytes

Comment: Dave, I'm having the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 6):

You can create a PdfReader from a MemoryStream, so long as the MemoryStream is a valid PDF object.  If the MemoryStream is a valid PDF object, then one way to initiate the PdfReader is this way:

```
PdfReader _reader = new PdfReader((byte[])_memoryStream.ToArray());
```

In the code below, the PdfReader is initialized from .Net Resource which is returned as a byte[] when called from the Properties.Resources object, so the Resource and the MemoryStream are returning the same type to the PdfReader, a byte[].  I then create a PdfStamper object from the PdfReader object, and use a MemoryStream as the resulting container for the PdfStamper.

```
PdfReader _srcDoc = new PdfReader(Properties.Resources.Resource1);
MemoryStream _output = new MemoryStream();
PdfStamper _scratchDoc = new PdfStamper(_srcDoc, _output);
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe a bit late.
Try to set the streams position to 0.

```
...
stream.Flush(); // Don't know if this is necessary
stream.Position = 0;
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(stream.ToArray());
...
```

Comment: PdfReader is a static class.  Instead of `new PdfReader(stream.ToArray)` it is now `PdfReader.Open(stream)`

Answer (score -3):

If you want to just open the pdf in browser using bytes then do this :

```
public void ReturnPDF(byte[] contents, string attachmentFilename)
        {
            var response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
            try
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(attachmentFilename))
                {
                    response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                    response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + attachmentFilename);
                }

                response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                response.BinaryWrite(contents);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                response.End();
                response.Flush();
                response.Clear();
            }


        }
```

Comment: I have a pdf in a memorystream and I need to read it with a PdfReader.       PdfReader rdr = new PdfReader(pdfstream); throws a "PDF header signature not found" error.

Comment: this usually mean that pdf file is corrupted

Comment: Not sure if the question wasn't clear in previous revisions, but this answer doesn't seem to apply at all.